# Get Process ID of Program Started with C# Process.Start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, putty

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

I am currently developing a program in C# 2010 that launches PLink (Putty) to create a SSH Tunnel. I am trying to make the program able to keep track of each tunnel that is open so a user may terminate those instances that are no longer needed. I am currently using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to run PLink (currently Putty being used). I need to determine the PID of each plink program when it is launched so a user can terminate it at will.

Question is how to do that and am I using the right .Net name space or is there something better?

Code snippet:

```
private void btnSSHTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String puttyConString;
    puttyConString = "-ssh -P " + cboSSHVersion.SelectedText + " -" + txtSSHPort.Text + " -pw " + txtSSHPassword.Text + " " + txtSSHUsername.Text + "@" + txtSSHHostname.Text;
    Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Putty\\putty.exe", puttyConString);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
private void btnSSHTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String puttyConString;
    puttyConString = "-ssh -P " + cboSSHVersion.SelectedText + " -" + txtSSHPort.Text + " -pw " + txtSSHPassword.Text + " " + txtSSHUsername.Text + "@" + txtSSHHostname.Text;
    Process putty = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Putty\\putty.exe", puttyConString);
    int processId = putty.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Process.Start returns a Process object. Use the `Process.Id` property to find out the id.

```
private void btnSSHTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String puttyConString;
        puttyConString = "-ssh -P " + cboSSHVersion.SelectedText + " -" + txtSSHPort.Text + " -pw " +        txtSSHPassword.Text + " " + txtSSHUsername.Text + "@" + txtSSHHostname.Text;
        Process started = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Putty\\putty.exe", puttyConString);
        //do anything with started.Id.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but `Process.Start` (at least the overload you're using) will return a `Process` and then that `Process` has an `Id` property.